# Presence not updating in Microsoft Teams using Graph API setPresence endpoint has context menu

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm utilizing the Microsoft Graph API's set presence endpoint ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[USERID]/presence/setPresence](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%5BUSERID%5D/presence/setPresence)) to update my presence in Microsoft Teams via Postman. Despite receiving a 200 OK response, my presence isn't reflecting the changes in the Microsoft Teams client even after waiting for 5-10 minutes.

Any help on this is appreciated!! Thanks :)

Comment: We checked this at our end, and it is working fine. You can also verify from other users machine if the status is reflecting or not. Also please note that there is a precedence order that is followed for setPresence. Please refer this doc for precedence order - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#presence-sessions

Comment: I verified the away status from my end, and it's not working properly.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the Teams? Is the issue happening in both Teams web client and desktop client. Could you please share the request id and timestamp at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Comment: Could you please share above details?